# unable to use rootScope inside window.onnotification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to use rootScope as global so that same can be retrieved in controller.

app.js:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform,$rootScope) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    pushNotification.register(
    onNotification,
    errorHandler,
  {
    'badge': 'true',
    'sound': 'true',
    'alert': 'true',
    'ecb': 'onNotification',
    'senderID': '999999999999',
  }
    );


  });
})

window.onNotification = function(e){

      switch(e.event){
        case 'registered':
          if(e.regid.length > 0){

            var device_token = e.regid;

              alert('registered :'+device_token);
              $rootScope.devicetoken = device_token;

          }
        break;

        case 'message':
          alert('msg received: ' + e.message);
          break;

        case 'error':
          alert('error occured');
        break;

      }
};

window.errorHandler = function(error){
  alert('an error occured');
}
```

I am getting device_token and getting in alert. but it is not going inside rootScope to use it in controller.

Controller.js:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('onWalletWelcomesCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal,User,$ionicLoading,$rootScope) {

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('signup-modal.html', {
      id: '1', // We need to use and ID to identify the modal that is firing the event!
      scope: $scope,
      backdropClickToClose: false,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.oModal1 = modal;
    });

    $scope.proceed = function(){
        alert($rootScope.devicetoken);
        $ionicLoading.show({template: '<ion-spinner icon="android"></ion-spinner>'});

    }

})
```

I am getting undefined while alerting in proceed function.
How should I use rootScope in window.onNotification. My main intention is to pass the devicetoken to controller. Please let me the best practice to share the variables.

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform,$rootScope) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    pushNotification.register(
    onNotification,
    errorHandler,
  {
    'badge': 'true',
    'sound': 'true',
    'alert': 'true',
    'ecb': 'onNotification',
    'senderID': '9999999999',
  }
    );

  });
})

window.onNotification = function(e){

      switch(e.event){
        case 'registered':
          if(e.regid.length > 0){

            var device_token = e.regid;

            alert('registered :'+device_token);
            $rootScope.devicetoken = "hi";
            $scope.$apply();

          }
        break;

        case 'message':
          alert('msg received: ' + e.message);

        break;

        case 'error':
          alert('error occured');
        break;

      }
};

window.errorHandler = function(error){
  alert('an error occured');
}
```

Still I am getting undefined while alerting in controller.

Comment: Try to define $rootScope.devicetoken = '';

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `window.onNotification = function(e){..}` declaration inside of your `.run(function($ionicPlatform,$rootScope) {...}` block.

$rootScope will be undefined in your onNotification handler where you currently have it placed - you need to declare your onNotification handler inside of the run() block so that it has access to the rootScope object while it is being defined.

Also, because you will be updating the rootScope with an event handler that lives outside of the angular lifecycle (angular doesn't know about it), you need to call trigger a new digest cycle manually. In your notification handler, you need to wrap your `$rootScope.devicetoken = device_token;` line with a $rootScope.apply(), so that it looks like this:

```
$rootScope.apply(function(){
      $rootScope.devicetoken = device_token;
});
```

Comment: no luck. I tried to keep onNotification inside but it is throwing unreferenced error

Comment: If you move it into the run block, then you WILL have access to a valid $rootScope object. If you did that, then something else is undefined. Have you tried debugging it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using $rootScope in `window.onNotification` so it is not angular context, so for you need to tell to angular to do updation.
So you need to add `$scope.$apply();` after `$rootScope` updation.

Comment: Can you provide any link to see and run the source ?

Comment: i tried both $scope.$apply() and $rootScope.$apply(). but no luck. still undefined while alerting inside controller

Answer (score -1):

Try to define $rootScope.devicetoken on the run scope

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform,$rootScope) {
    $rootScope.devicetoken = '';
```

make sure that window.onNotification executed before $scope.proceed

Comment: $rootScope is a global, angular-provided object. You shouldn't have to initialize it yourself, and even if you did, it would be an object.